# Azure Ad b2c custompolicy starter pack local signin

Tags: azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I have tried to make custom policies. then I used custom policy starter pack from https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack.git

First I registered new user, then I tried sign In process but it doesn't work.
Error message says "The username or password provided in the request are invalid"

Do you have any solution of this?

*I registered B2C_1A_TokenSigningKeyContainer and B2C_1A_TokenEncryptionKeyContainer.
*And I replaced each keys particular place on SignUpOrSignin.xml(followed the guidance from microsoft web page )

Comment: Did you finish [this step](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-get-started#add-application-ids-to-the-custom-policy) to put the id of your IEF and ProxyIEF into TrustFrameworkExtensions.xml?

Comment: Hi,Ray Thnaks for your replying.I changed that part, but I set these keys opposite positions. So now custom policy worked. Thanks for your suggestion :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the common causes of this issue is the misconfiguration of application IDs of `IdentityExperienceFramework` and `ProxyIdentityExperienceFramework`.

Check out [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-get-started#add-application-ids-to-the-custom-policy) to make sure the configuration is correct.